# What happens to incapacitated soldiers?

Tags: sniper-elite-v2

In Sniper Elite V2, when you incapacitate an enemy soldier by scoring a non-lethal hit, they fall to the ground and start calling for help. If left alone, they'll die soon enough, but occasionally another enemy soldier will walk up and carry them off somewhere.

What happens to them after that? Do they still die, just somewhere else? Are they removed from the game, costing you a kill? Do they get fixed up and rejoin the fight later? Something else entirely?

Comment: I'm sure they get ample medical care, a cup of hot cocoa, and a nice Red Cross package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From personal experience of being a bit sick in the head and playing a good bit of Sniper Elite V2.  When you incapacitate an enemy on the battlefield and allow his buddy to pick him up, the "still standing" enemy will bring the wounded soldier to the sides of the battlefield out of the way and set him down, then return to the battlefield.  After you kill him you can go to the wounded enemy who may or may not still be alive.  They can bleed out if they have been moved, or they could still be alive.  I have not personally seen one get bandaged up and return to the battle.  There is a chance that they could de-spawn as a result of being "saved" but I do not know that for sure either.  I hope this helps!